# how can I bind an input to a property deep within a complicated data structure?

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular-rails resource with a property that consists of irregular data that is potentially quite complicated-- something like:

```
 { foo: [ { bar: 'baz', lol: [ { 'omg': ... etc
```

I built a directive which takes this data and drills down into it, dynamically rendering form fields for each object...  I've got the data displaying perfectly, however the piece of the puzzle that's missing is, how can I take advantage of Angular's binding so that changing the value on the form input will actually update that attribute in the model?

Originally I was thinking this should be simple, as my code drills through the data structure, it can just be maintaining a path, so I'd end up with something like:  'myObject.foo.bar'

Then I could just pass that to the form input's ng-model attribute...... however, I could not get angular to recognize ng-model="path" where $scope.path = "myObject.foo.bar"...  ng-model="{{path}}" did not work either.

My directive is using angular.forEach to drill down into this datastructure, and someone had mentioned to me that I should perhaps be using ng-repeat instead, but I wasn't sure if this is the correct way to go or not?  I still feel like there should just be a way to do ng-model="path" and have that work...

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To use dynamic property names, use array notation. I.e. myObject["foo"]["bar"]. Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/W60F75?p=preview

Comment: The point was, I need a variable that can be assigned to a string that I append to-- something that ends up being "myObject.foo.bar".  I tried what you suggested and it does not work-- see here: http://plnkr.co/edit/xo81F3NE6ABEl9M4AdYH?p=preview

Comment: Ah... I don't know of a way to do it with a completely dynamic object name/property hierarchy. Any working solution would probably involve eval... What your plunker does no is replacing the object pointed to by $scope.path with the string input in the field.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting an property on the scope with the value of the object itself and then refer it in the form element? Like below:

```
// In your script
$scope.obj = myObject;

// In your form
<input ng-model="obj.foo.bar" type="text" />
```